# Como adicionar um ícone mostrando que aquele item já foi lido, sendo salva as preferências usando SharedPreferences?

Tags: android

Essa é uma parte do menu inicial do aplicativo:

#### Tela Inicial

A imagem abaixo representa a tela inicial do aplicativo, que possui os botões "como usar" e "Introdução a dinâmica", para o usuário escolher que tarefa vai fazer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Tela "Como usar"

Clicando no `ImagemButton` (acima do texto "Como Usar") o usuário vai para um novo *Layout* no qual tem um botão <kbd>voltar para tela principal</kbd> para que possa seguir em frente para as próximas etapas do tutorial, como abaixo:

[image: Representação da tela do "como usar"]

## Dúvida

Depois que o usuário tenha entrado no *layout* do "como usar", ter lido e concluído clicando no botão <kbd>voltar para tela principal</kbd> queria que aparecesse um ícone no `ImagemButton` para notificar que ele já concluiu aquela tarefa. Assim, quando o usuário entrar no aplicativo novamente, ele poderá saber quais ele já fez e continuar de onde ele parou. Como representado abaixo:

[image: tela como deveria ficar após a conclusão do "como usar"]

Quais recursos/metodos do Android eu devo usar para que posso adicionar um ícone mostrando que aquele item já foi lido?

Comment: Cara, está meio confuso mais entendi um pouco do que você quer. Na media que vai respondendo as perguntas, o botão se altera certo?

Comment: Amigo, reformulei a pergunta... espero que esteja melhor

Comment: Não entendi, que respostas?

Comment: Ah ta! Dentro de "Como user" tem alguma interação com o usuário ou é simplesmente uma "layout"?

Comment: É simplesmente uma Layout com um botão para voltar para o menu... As outras tarefas tem uma interação maior do que essa "como usar", mas acredito que sabendo fazer essa mais simples, que só tem esse botão "Ir para tela principal", as outras darão certo também...

Comment: São muitas telas ou poucas? Dá pra fazer de várias formas.

Comment: Esse como usar só tem uma... só um detalhe que pode importar já que você acredita que possui varias formas de resolver... eu fiz o aplicativo inteiro com a mesma Activity, eu abro apenas layouts diferentes...

Comment: Se você estiver se referindo a interação com o usuário devido o nome Dinâmica, ele é nome do assunto tratado no aplicativo... é um aplicativo para auxiliar professores de Física no Ensino Médio...

Comment: Então teria que colocar a lógica a principio no clicar do botão para entrar no seu layout. Tipo, clicou e abriu o layout, já tornaria como lida. Seria a forma mais viável no momento por você está usando a mesma Activity. Se fosse algo mais rigoroso, daria pra fazer tipo além do usuário clicar e entrar no layout, poderia exigir que rolasse o app até no final etc.

Comment: Ótimo, clicando no botão e já adicionando é o suficiente... seria adicionado assim que ele entrasse no layout de como usar, certo?

Comment: Existem outras maneiras de fazer além da resposta que acabei de publicar. Caso tire totalmente sua dúvida, faça uma breve pesquisa sobre persistência de dados, porque pelo que percebemos, é o que você está precisando. Caso não persista os dados, toda vez que você abrir sua aplicação, vai ficar com valores padrões do desenvolvimento.

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado por estar me ajudando, mas é que eu sou novo em programação... estou ainda tentando colocar o que vc propôs no app... apareceu alguns erros e estou tentando ver se da certo, vou ver uns vídeos e ler sobre persistência de dados e SharedPreferences... Assim que der certo ou se eu não conseguir dou um retorno... O primeiro erro que surgiu foi "boolean tela1..." talvez eu não tenha definido o botão como visualizado corretamente...

Comment: Tranquilo! Eu também estive ai no seu lugar e pedindo ajuda para outras pessoas. Nas horas vagas estou sempre tentando ajudar. Qualquer coisa, recorre aqui! abs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você mencionou, para casos de coleção relativamente pequena de valores-chave para salvar, use as APIs [**SharedPreferences**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html?hl=pt-br). Um objeto `SharedPreferences` indica um arquivo que contém pares de valores-chave e fornece métodos simples para ler e gravar.

> Cada arquivo SharedPreferences é gerenciado pela estrutura de trabalho
>   e pode ser privado ou compartilhado.

Primeiramente pode definir uma *string* estática para dar o nome de sua configuração e declarar a imagem que vai surgir com o click do botão:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Preferences";
private ImageView img;
```

Depois criamos um método para ser adicionada a imagem quando o botão for clicado e ser salva uma preferência, desta forma:

```
private void onOff() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    settings.edit().putBoolean("online", true).apply();

    boolean online = settings.getBoolean("online", false);
    if (online) {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.confirmacao);
    } else {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.fundo);
    }
}
```

Para resgatar o valor gravado basta você verificar desta forma, na tela em que a imagem se encontra:

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
Boolean online = settings.getBoolean("online", false);

if (online)
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.confirmacao);
else
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.fundo);
```

Pro fim, você deve colocar esse método `onOff();` no botão que desejar.

Sendo assim, você vai fazer essa verificação acima toda vez que entrar na sua aplicação. Lembrando que é uma maneira rápida de fazer e pode ser otimizada. Isso é só um exemplo básico para que tenha mais noção.

Observações:

1 - "img" é o id da imagem que não possui background definido no layout e é onde é inserida a imagem confirmação.

2 - "confrimacao" é o nome do arquivo da imagem que representa a notificação de visualizado.

3 - "fundo" é o nome de um arquivo de uma imagem com nada (transparente) salva em .png

4 - Talvez o método `onOff();` possa ser acionado em qualquer botão do meu aplicativo devido eu usar apenas uma Activity em todo o app.

5 - Existe um vídeo na pagina do artigo "Muito além do SQLite" (proposto abaixo) que pode ajudar muito.

Existem outras técnicas de persistência como alternativa, simples e ágeis, que permitem a persistência de pequenas quantidades de dados. São elas:

• `PreferenceActivity`;

• `Internal Storage`;

• `Armazenamento em Cache`;

• `External Storage`.

Veja alguns artigos:

- [Persistência de dados no Android](http://www.devmedia.com.br/persistencia-de-dados-no-android/26947)
- [Muito além do SQLite](http://www.devmedia.com.br/persistencia-de-dados-com-android-muito-alem-do-sqlite-revista-webmobile-magazine-36/21435)
- [Opções de Armazenamento](https://zarelli.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/android-opcoes-de-armazenamento/)
- [Persistência em Banco de Dados](http://www.rafaeltoledo.net/tutorial-android-11-persistencia-em-banco-de-dados/)

Comment: Esse artigo que você propôs "Muito além do SQLite" parece que iria me mostrar exatamente o que falta para que eu consiga, mas ele é pago...

Comment: @TonyÁlaffe verdade, esqueci desse detalhe. Na verdade é assim, o SQLite é para quantidade muito grande de dados, nesse teu caso não precisaria. Este artigo mostra outras alternativas para quantidades pequenas de armazenamentos. Mas tem outros artigos bons na internet que você pode estar acessando. Tem dois gringos referência que gosto muito de seguir para aprender coisas novas, o [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/) e [Ravi Tamada](http://www.androidhive.info/). Se quiser aprender de verdade, veja os tutoriais deles. Recomendo!

Comment: Ack Lay, deu certo! ficou muito bom! No artigo "Muito Além do SQLite" tem um vídeo que explica algo bem parecido com o que eu queria, daí aprendi a fazer o do vídeo e depois encaixei essa sua sugestão e acabou que deu certo! Muito Obrigado Novamente, me ajudou d+!

Comment: A questão é: eu devo editar sua respostas incrementando o que falta pra que dê certo ou devo criar uma resposta mostrando como ficou? Eu não entendo muito bem como aqui funciona... perdi 4 pontos de reputação por que coloquei essa pergunta como do Android Studio (Ainda não sei por que).

Comment: @TonyÁlaffe é muito complicado essa questão de negativar aqui no SO. Tem muita gente que não sabe ainda como usar esse botão do down. Talvez negativaram você por não tem um pouco de esforço pesquisa na sua pergunta. Geralmente tem que haver código, etc. e mais clareza, além de formatação. Leia aqui [como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); e [tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @TonyÁlaffe se minha resposta te ajudou e você tem um complemento para ela, sugiro fazer a edição da minha resposta incrementado o que você tem. Agora se for totalmente diferente, você pode adicionar uma nova resposta a sua pergunta. Fique a vontade! Como você não tem reputação suficiente, sua edição passara por uma ouvidoria que posteriormente será aprovada se for condizente. Sugiro também marcar a resposta como válida se caso for realmente valida.

Comment: @TonyÁlaffe vou editar sua pergunta um pouco. Veja.

Comment: @TonyÁlaffe editei tentando não sair do objetivo, porém foi custoso. hehe

Comment: Mas melhorou muito mesmo!!! Assim que tiver reputação suficiente, vou apenas colocar a imagem do antes, para que tenha o ante e o depois...

Comment: Eu editei a resposta, você pode ver como ficou?

Comment: @TonyÁlaffe perfeito. Eu aprovei. Agora você precisa apenas marcar a resposta como correta, e assim é finalizada a questão. Se precisar, dê um toque aqui. Abs.

Comment: Consegui reputação suficiente, editei e já marquei como correta. Abs... Sei que é difícil, mas se precisar, também to por aqui.